# setOnMouseClicked doesnt work after enabling depth buffer on subscene

Tags: java, 3d, javafx-8, javafx-3d

For a project I need a click listener on a 3D Object. After enabling the depth buffer in my subscene the listener doesn't work anymore.

```
boolean enableDepthBuffer = Platform.isSupported(ConditionalFeature.SCENE3D);
subScene = new SubScene(graphPane, primaryScreenBounds.getWidth() / 1.2, primaryScreenBounds.getHeight() / 1.2,
            enableDepthBuffer, SceneAntialiasing.BALANCED);
```

If I set enableDepthBuffer to false all my listeners inside the subScene work fine again.

Is there a way to fix this behaviour?